# R - programming practices for parameter inputs

Tags: r, input, parameters

as I am quite new to R, I'm looking for a nice way to organise parameter input and parsing in R.

My program has to be run with many instances of data and parameters. At the moment it's done like this:

for every run I have a subdirectory where a datafile (say data.RData) and a corresponding parameter specification (say params.R) lies. Then I have a bash script, which (via Rscript) starts my R program (say main.R) given these two files. Then main.R sources params.R, calls a function to load data.RData and then calls further functions to compute something with the data.

Are there better ways? Or what are the usual ways?

The way I am doing it, all the parameters from params.R are global variables when I run main.R, which seems not so ideal.

Comment: The best first approach is the one that works. If your program is slow, then search for bottlenecks and optimize.  I usually follow the same approach that you use by separating: functions, data reading/writing, parameter definition.